# Find in json and set in another json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have **JSON 1** with this data

```
{position: 1, weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
{position: 2, weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}
```

And I have another **JSON 2** with this data

```
{position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
{position: 2, name: 'Helium'}
```

I show this data in the angular-material table

```
POSITION   |   WEIGHT   |   SYMBOL
1          |   1.0079   |   H
2          |   4.0026   |   He
```

I need to search in the second JSON elements with position number  **1** or **2** etc..., and set **name** instead of number, and get first JSON table like this

```
POSITION   |   WEIGHT   |   SYMBOL
Hydrogen   |   1.0079   |   H
Helium     |   4.0026   |   He
```

Is there any direct way to do this instead of push all data to new JSON?

I try, because I use ngrx@store, to make selector and get data directly to the table in HTML but i get infinity loop

```
export const selectElements = createSelector(
  selectElements , 
  element => (position: string) => element [position]
);

this.elements= this.store.pipe(
  select(elements.selectElements )
);
```

and in material table

```
{{ (elements | async)(elements.position) }}
```

and get error in VScode

> Call target is not callable

I also try to use **.find()** but the same error, infinity loop...

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-lkm8y9?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Can't you update the first JSON before serving to the table?

Comment: I only need to change this number => name on one specific place in app, on any another place I need number and because of this I hope there is some solution to change this from html table like this `{{ (elements | async)(elements.position) }} ` like i explain what I try, but for some reason this going in infinity loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use filter as below:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterData'
})
export class OrdinalPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Element): string {
    var data =   ElementTitle.filter(
          ElementTitle => ElementTitle.position === value);
          return  data[0].name; 
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position |FilterData }} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
```

Here is the URL with filter feature.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttg6ux-sokueh?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts

Comment: very nice and smooth... thnx

Comment: search not working for this row with FilterData pipe...  do you know how to fix this? Thnx

Comment: @Arter Please add below code in your component.                                                                ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
 var dataa =   ELEMENT_DATA_TITLE.filter(
          element => element.position === data.position );
      return data.position.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter) 
      || data.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
      || data.position.toString().toLowerCase() === filter
      || dataa[0].name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase());
    };
  }

Comment: can you pls try to add it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttg6ux?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts

Comment: also add below code for search:                                                                          
public doFilter = (value: string) => {
value = value.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    value = value.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = value;
  }

Comment: this is great.... pls put yr answer here .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645962/find-in-json-and-set-in-another-json/59647224?noredirect=1#comment105518209_59647224

Comment: @Arter https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttg6ux-sokueh?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts Please check this URL.

Comment: on a link I give you, I ask this question, and If you want you can put it there so I can accept it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645962/find-in-json-and-set-in-another-json/59647224?noredirect=1#comment105518209_59647224 This link redirecting me to this page only. Kindly give that question link i'll put my asnwer there. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677176/search-in-material-table-not-working-with-pipe/59677311#59677311 thnx

Comment: @Arter Done Please check..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `reduce()` and `find()` combination to resolve your issue.

As [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) documentation states:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {position: 1, weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'}
], arr2 = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium'}
];

const result = arr2.reduce((a, c) => {
  const elem = arr1.find(e => e.position === c.position);
  
  a.push({
    name: c.name,
    weight: elem.weight,
    symbol: elem.symbol
  })
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!