# Search in material-table not working with pipe

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my material table I use `@pipe` to get **name** instead of **position** in position row...

I get a **name** from another **JSON** file...

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position | FilterData }} </mat-cell>
```

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterData'
})
export class OrdinalPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Element): string {
    var data =   ElementTitle.filter(
          ElementTitle => ElementTitle.position === value);  // ElementTitle is second JSON file
          return  data[0].name; 
  }
}
```

And now when I try to use **SEARCH BOX** in angular-material table to search by **name** there is no data, but if I enter **position number** I get filtered data properly.

Probably, problem is because **datatables data** is taken from a component but **pipe** change data in html...

How to TELL mat-table to also search by piped data in table?

Here is working example, try to search by the name (Nitrogen, Helium etc...) 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttg6ux?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

export interface Element {
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export interface ElementTitle {
  name: string;
  position: number;
}


/**
 * @title Table with filtering
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-filtering-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-filtering-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-filtering-example.html',
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
   displayedColumns = ['position', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string): boolean {
 var dataa =   ELEMENT_DATA_TITLE.filter(
          element => element.position === data.position );
      return data.position.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter) 
      || data.symbol.toLowerCase().includes(filter)
      || data.position.toString().toLowerCase() === filter
      || dataa[0].name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase());
    };
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }

}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'xx'},
  {position: 2, weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'xx'},
  {position: 3, weight: 6.941, symbol: 'xyx'},
  {position: 4, weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'xyx'},
  {position: 5, weight: 10.811, symbol: 'xyx'},
  {position: 6, weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'yy'},
  {position: 7, weight: 14.006, symbol: 'yy'},
  {position: 8, weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'yy'},
  {position: 9, weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'yy'}
];

const ELEMENT_DATA_TITLE: ElementTitle[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine'}
];


import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterData'
})
export class OrdinalPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    var data =   ELEMENT_DATA_TITLE.filter(
          element => element.position === value );
          return  data[0].name; 
  }
}
```

Example HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position | FilterData}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Please refer below URL :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttg6ux-sokueh?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts

Please let me know if you face any difficulty.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Material Table I suggest you to also use MatTableDataSource. Declare it at the begining of your typescript and load its data like if it were an array or a list.

`datasource :MatTableDataSource<any>;`

```
someMethodToLoadData(){
   // get your data
   this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(data);
}
```

With datasource now you can use its native property **filter**:

***typescript***

```
filterTable (filterValue :string) { 
   this.datasource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(); 
}
```

***html***

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput (keyup)="filterTable($event.target.value)">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thnx, i already use this, because filtering working for all part of table, but for this with pipe not